# Quickly align edge loop?

Tags: modeling, edges

I am trying clean up topology, and I have found an issue which I will have to do a TON work for this mesh.

I have a line of vertices I would like to quickly make straight. You can do this in the UV/Image editor by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> > Align X or Y.

Is there any possible way to achieve this is the 3D View?

[image: vertices unaligned]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the edge loop in your picture, with the [Pivot Point](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point)  set to *Median Point*, *Individual Origins*, or *Bounding Box Center*, you can press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> `0`.

That will scale all the selected vertices along the Y axis to 0, meaning all together, because the scaling is constrained to the Y axis, you will get a straight line perpendicular to the Y axis.

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> `0` for the X axis
<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> `0` for the Y axis
<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `0` for the Z axis

Comment: And make sure the pivot is set to median or bounds, if it's set to cursor you'll get a the points aligned and moved elsewhere at the same time.

Comment: @StarWeaver excellent point, edit my answer to include it.